# How to calculate the workspace of a five bar planar parallel robotic manipulator using MATLAB?

Tags: inverse-kinematics, matlab, forward-kinematics

I am trying to calculate the workspace of a five bar planar parallel manipulator using MATLAB. Also, I am trying to plot the exact workspace as shown( kindly check the link). For this I guess I need to model the robot how should it be done?

[Perform Forward and Inverse Kinematics on a Five-Bar Robot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ug/five_bar_robot.html)

Comment: what does this mean? ... `I am unable to execute it` ... please edit your post .. add an description of what happens

Comment: Hi Nanase thanks for asking your question here. To be well formed your question needs more information. Please see the guide for asking a good question here: https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist